# Angular 4 transition/transform with classes?

Tags: angular, class, animation, transition

I have to classes for my button for example "btn-hero-success" and "btn-hero-danger" 
is there any way to transition between these 2 classes without writing style in animation?

my sample code:

```
<button [ngClass]="{'btn-hero-success': !disableAddToCloudButton, 'btn-hero-danger': disableAddToCloudButton" (click)="addOrRemoveKeyword(tagCloud.id)">
   <i [ngClass]="{'ion-plus-round': !disableAddToCloudButton, 'ion-close-round': disableAddToCloudButton}"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: You're setting the "class" property twice, try to fix it before going on

Comment: I remove extra classes.